# My code isn't giving the output as required .Any idea to fix this?

Tags: android

I'm looking to display two of my starting activities once the app is executed for the first time in the device.
I used shared preferences to do the job, but this isn't working as I want.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("test", "on Main 2");
        try {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 
0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            boolean firstTime = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first", false);

            Log.d("test", "on Main 2 shared Preference");

            if (!firstTime) {

                Log.d("test", "on Main 2 shared Preference,check if it appeared 
for the first time.");

                //running for the first time;
                editor.putBoolean("first", true);

                editor.apply();
                //if running for the first time then jump from this activity to 
Main3.
                Log.d("test", "on Main 2 shared Preference,going  to Main3");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2.this, Main3.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.d("test", "going to main 3 ");
                finish();
            } else {
                //if not running for the first time then jump from this activity 
to Main3.
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2.this, SendMessage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
```

The same piece of code is used for the other class with different class names.
The code is:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        boolean firstTime = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first", false);

        if (!firstTime) {
            //running for the first time;
            editor.putBoolean("first", true);

            editor.apply();
            //if running for the first time then jump from this activity to Main4.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main3.this, Main4.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            //if not running for the first time then jump from this activity to Main4.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main3.this, Main4.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

`Main4` is the activity we want to display every time the app starts.
The app when started jumps directly to the `Main4` activity without displaying `Main2` and `Main3`.I think there's some problem with my intents.

Please, suggest ideas for this problem!

Comment: If you are supposed to display main2 if it is the first time, you have a wrong intent. directing to Main4 instead of main 2

Comment: And what exactly is "output as required"?

Comment: I want to display these two activities once when the app is executed for the first time when it's installed in the device.

Comment: So you add intents to the appropriate activities. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it's not displaying the activities I want to show .Can you tell,where actually I should place the intents.